# Error when adding migration to EntityFramework project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Working on a .NETCore MVC back end that's using EntityFramework.
The Solution as a Service project, EntityFramework project, and an API (MVC) project. The API project is the envy point/startup. 
It's an existing project, and there was an initial migration file which I used to setup the database from the command line using: `dotnet ef database update`. 
Now, I've added a new model to the EntityFramework project, and added the appropriate `public DbSet` to the Context class. Now I'm trying to generate the update migration file for it so I can update the database. 
Using `dotnet ef migrations add migration_002` gave an error of:

> Unable to create an object of type 'StartNetContext'. Add an
>   implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to
>   the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for
>   additional patterns supported at design time.

Searching for that turned up posts and blogs related to upgrades from EF 1 -> 2 ... not appropriate in this case. Or pointing to issues when creating the initial migration when there's also seeding happening... again, also not appropriate in this case. When I add the -v option, I get a bit more info:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to
>   create an object of type 'StartNetContext'. Add an implementation of
>   'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns
>   supported at design time. ---> System.MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Ugh. What? Why do I need that? Searching that points to re-arranging how the startup is configured... specifically making sure that the. `AddDbContext` is being called - which it is...

I feel like I'm going in circles... it should work... someone created the initial migration, so it had to have worked, right?

NOTE: I'm on a Mac, so there's no using the Package Manager console, so selecting target projects, etc isn't a solution either. This all needs to be done right from the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class in your main project.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
{
    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>();
        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDbContextConnectionName");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new YourDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Hope your error will go away!

Comment: I did . that and got errors on the return line. Oddly enough, it ended up being simple - no code needed. I just needed to add -s ../MyMainApp.Api to the CLI command... and BAM! problem went away and my migration file was created. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out in my case it was a simple flag on the CLI... Despite having the web api project marked as the startup project in the solution, I needed to specify it on the command line as well.

`dotnet ef migrations add migration_002 -s ../MyWebApp.Api`

I got that from [this post](https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/).
Adding the -s flag worked, even without the code and adding the class (which I did try first, but ran into problems with the return statement). 
It's the simple things in life.